# React Native App restarts on navigating to a page using react-native-maps-directions

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-native-maps

I'm using expo and react native. I have about 8 different screens I'm navigating between, but on navigating to a page that is supposed to display a map, the app restarts and goes back to the splash screen.
The code works fine in the emulator and my expo app. But the error occurs in the Binary build (APK). This page contains data from 'react-native-maps', and 'react-native-maps-directions'.

I tried replacing this page with a simple hello world page and it works fine then. It's just this particular map code that isn't working as expected. I'm using:

"expo": "~37.0.3", "react": "~16.9.0", "react-native-maps": "0.26.1", "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",

I can't figure out why this is happening. I've attached the code below. Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 37.771707;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4053769;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'MY_KEY';

class MapScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      coordinates: [
        {
          latitude: 12.822960,
          longitude: 80.041929,
        },
        {
          latitude: 13.009027, 
          longitude: 80.222075,
        },
      ],
    };

    this.mapView = null;
  }

  onMapPress = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      coordinates: [
        ...this.state.coordinates,
        e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
      ],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: LATITUDE,
          longitude: LONGITUDE,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        ref={c => this.mapView = c}
        onPress={this.onMapPress}
      >
        {this.state.coordinates.map((coordinate, index) =>
          <MapView.Marker key={`coordinate_${index}`} coordinate={coordinate} />
        )}
        {(this.state.coordinates.length >= 2) && (
          <MapViewDirections
            origin={this.state.coordinates[0]}
            destination={this.state.coordinates[this.state.coordinates.length-1]}
            apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
            strokeWidth={3}
            strokeColor="hotpink"
            optimizeWaypoints={true}
            onStart={(params) => {
              console.log(`Started routing between "${params.origin}" and "${params.destination}"`);
            }}
            onReady={result => {
              console.log(`Distance: ${result.distance} km`)
              console.log(`Duration: ${result.duration} min.`)

              this.mapView.fitToCoordinates(result.coordinates, {
                edgePadding: {
                  right: (width / 20),
                  bottom: (height / 20),
                  left: (width / 20),
                  top: (height / 20),
                }
              });
            }}
            onError={(errorMessage) => {
              // console.log('GOT AN ERROR');
            }}
          />
        )}
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}

export default MapScreen;
```

Comment: Did anyone resolved this issue ? '